# Factory pattern Design

Tags: php, arrays, parameters, factory-pattern

I have a factory based class such as this:

```
class AisisCore_Factory_Pattern {

    protected static $_class_instance;

    protected static $_dependencies;

    public static function get_instance(){
        if(self::$_class_instance == null){
            $_class_instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$_class_instance;
    }

    public static function create($class){
        if(empty($class)){
            throw new AisisCore_Exceptions_Exception('Class cannot be empty.');
        }

        if(!isset(self::$_dependencies)){
            throw new AisisCore_Exceptions_Exception('There is no dependencies array created. 
                Please create one and register it.');   
        }

        if(!isset(self::$_dependencies[$class])){
            throw new AisisCore_Exceptions_Exception('This class does not exist in the dependecies array!');
        }

        if(isset(self::$_dependencies[$class]['params'])){
            $new_class =  new $class(implode(', ', self::$_dependencies[$class]['params']));
            return $new_class;
        }else{
            $new_class = new $class();
            return $new_class;
        }
    }

    public static function register_dependencies($array){
        self::$_dependencies = $array;
    }

}
```

Now with this class we do the following:

**First set up our class list and their dependencies**

```
$class_list = array(
    'class_name_here' => array(
        'params' => array(
            'cat'
        ) 
    )
);
```

**Register them:**

```
AisisCore_Factory_Pattern::register_dependencies($class_list);
```

This means that any time you call the create method and pass it a class we will return you a new instance of that class, while also passing in any parameters for that class.

**Create a Clas**

To create a class all we do is:

```
$object = AisisCore_Factory_Pattern::register_dependencies('class_name_here');
```

And now we have created a new instance of class: `class_name_here` and pasing it the parameter of `cat`, and now all we have to do to access its methods is do `$object->method()`

**My question with all this is:**

What if a parameter is an array? How do I deal with that?

One solution could be:

```
public static function create($class){

    if(isset(self::$_dependencies[$class]['params'])){
        if(is_array(self::$_dependencies[$class]['params'])){
            $ref = new ReflectionClass($class);
            return $ref->newInstanceArgs(self::$_dependencies[$class]['params']);
        }
        $new_class =  new $class(implode(', ', self::$_dependencies[$class]['params']));
        return $new_class;
    }else{
        $new_class = new $class();
        return $new_class;
    }
}
```

Comment: You *may* want to look into `Zend\Di`, which basically does what you're trying to repeat... https://github.com/ralphschindler/Zend_DI-Examples

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet in this situation is to probably use the reflection class to create a new instance passing in the array of arguments. see [reflectionclass::newinstanceargs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php) and
the user comments has something similar like:

```
$ref = new ReflectionClass($class);
return $ref->newInstanceArgs(self::$_dependencies[$class]['params']);
```

this should work like [call_user_func_array](http://www.php.net/call_user_func_array) in that each value in the array is passed as a different argument to the function.